# dynamically add spritesheets to sequenceData array in corona

Tags: lua, lazy-loading, coronasdk

Problem: I have a long duration frame-based animation for which i have created many spritesheets (e.g. 50 spritesheets with 10 images in each - 2 MB per spritesheet). It takes noticeable time (and memory) to pre-load all 50 spritesheets before the animation can be played using code based on the example code snippet below (this is suggested in the corona docs):

```
local function spriteListener( event )
    thisSprite = event.target  -- "event.target" references the sprite

    if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then 
        sequenceNumer = sequenceNumer + 1;

        if (sequenceNumer <=10) then
            thisSprite:setSequence(filenameArray[sequenceNumer])
            thisSprite:play()
        end
    end
end
local spriteWidth = 551
local spriteHeight = 401
local numFrames1 = 15
local startFrame = 1

frameInfoSet1 = {width = spriteWidth , height = spriteHeight, numFrames = numFrames1}

filenameArray = {"001-015","016-030","031-045","046-060","061-075","076-090","091-105","106-120","121-135","136-150"}

fullSequence = 
{
    {name=filenameArray[1], sheet=graphics.newImageSheet("spritesheets/" .. filenameArray[1] .. ".png", frameInfoSet1), start = startFrame, count=numFrames1, time=2250, loopCount=1},
    {name=filenameArray[2], sheet=graphics.newImageSheet("spritesheets/" .. filenameArray[2] .. ".png", frameInfoSet1), start = startFrame, count=numFrames1, time=2250, loopCount=1},
    {name=filenameArray[3], sheet=graphics.newImageSheet("spritesheets/" .. filenameArray[3] .. ".png", frameInfoSet1), start = startFrame, count=numFrames1, time=2250, loopCount=1},
-- more such spritesheets are loaded further...
}

firstSpriteSheet = fullSequence[1]["sheet"]

sequenceNumer = 1

tt = display.newSprite (firstSpriteSheet, fullSequence)
tt.x = display.contentWidth/2 ; tt.y = display.contentHeight/2
tt:addEventListener( "sprite", spriteListener )
tt:play()
```

However, what i would like to achieve is a "streaming" version of this technique. i.e. I will load only 3 spritesheets out of the total of 50, therefore requiring say 6 MB to start playing the animation and keep loading additional spritesheets as the already loaded ones keep playing. So, to illustrate further, i load sheets 1,2,3 and start playing the animation and load sheet 4 by the time sheet 1 is finished, load sheet 5 by the time sheet 2 is finished and so on.

Any advice is appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so it is possible. Try reduce size of imagesheets instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old question, but I will add thoughts from my expirience:

This is not an easy task, but it's possible

1. Preload sheets before you go

I suggest to add simple loading scene, where you will show progress bar while loading.

```lua
local filenameArray = ... -- this is from your code
local preloadedSheets = {}

local function enterFrameLoading()
  local nextSheetToLoad = #preloadedSheets + 1
  if (nextSheetToLoad > #filenameArray) then
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameLoading)
    -- go to game scene if you are using scenes
    return
  end

  preloadedSheets[nextSheetToLoad] = 
        graphics.newImageSheet("spritesheets/" .. filenameArray[nextSheetToLoad] .. ".png", ??)

  updateProgress(nextSheetToLoad) -- this function will update UI, i.e. progress bar, text, etc
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameLoading)
```

After preloading all sheets will be in memory, so you shouldn't have performance issues

2. Use multiple sprite objects, created on demand

You can create new objects inside `spriteListener` - again, store all sprites inside a table and use `.isVisible = false` to hide old sprites

3. Combine solutions 1 and 2

You can create sprite objects with just 3 sequences. Then preload other sheets in enterFrame listener like I showed above.

When preloading is finished you want to destroy old sprite and create new with the same sequence and frame

Let me know if you need more information on this